# Rattling of a Shimano Nexave roller brake

Tags: brakes, noise

In a suspended fork I use a Shimano Nexave BR-IM75-F roller brake and the cooling disc of the brake is not tighly fixed on the hub and it was like that since I got the roller-brake installed. I'm not sure whether this is "by design" or a fault. Opening the brrake side of the hub didn'r reveal nay way to make the fit tigher.

Anyway, It works fine for stoppping, but when I go over rough terrain the disc seems to rattles a lot, which creates quite a bit of noise. - Not nice!

Any idea what I can do?

Here is a picture of the Brake (I hope it helps understanding the situation!):
[image: pictureofbrake]

Comment: I've only read of 2-3 installs of that style brake, but the complaint was always rattling/rubbing.

Comment: @Daniel-R-Hicks Any idea what *to do* about it?

Comment: 'Fraid not.  It's a rare beast, and not many folks have experience with it.

Comment: Here is the official Manual of your brake. Does not tell anything about looseness of the coooling disc though, only some amount of play when braking is mentioned. HTH http://www.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/RollerBrake/BRIM75F/SI-75C0A-002_EN_v1_m56577569830655414.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I have these fitted to my Carrera Subway 8.

They seem to work well, but yes they rattle quite a bit when going over rough ground.  The cooling fin becomes tight when the brakes are applied so must be a direct connection to one of the friction faces.

I might have a go a dabbing a bit of silicone at three points around the interface of the cooling fin to see if it subdues the rattling :-)

Comment: Hello Kris, welcome to bicycles SE! Please make sure to **answer** the question when writing an answer, backed up by reference or personal experience. Your answer seems more like a comment. Maybe you could edit it to improve it?

Comment: This also fits my experience. Have Shimano BR-IM 80 Roller brakes, and the cooling discs are loose when the brake is not applied. Got used to the noise they make (or maybe it is not so much with my system). I cannot back this up, but I think that this is by design. If it helps, here is the manual for my brake: http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/SI_8G80B/SI_8G80A/SI-8G80A-001-ENG_v1_m56577569830676446.pdf

Comment: @Paul_Weber Thanks for the manual. - I have a hard time getting used to the noise. Not sure what to do: I got the brake especially so that I can separate the brake cable from the brake (I have a splittable recumbent)...

Answer (score 1):

I have a front brake similar to yours (BR-IM70-F) and had the same problem. It turned out that I had not tightened the "brake unit fixing nut" properly which is the item number 2 in [this document](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/BR/EV-BR-IM70-F-2205B_v1_m56577569830728395.pdf). According to [another document](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/RollerBrake/BR-IM70/SI-75F0B-001-EN_v1_m56577569830728642.pdf) the nut should be tightened with a torque of 15-20 nm.

Answer (score 0):

I was irritated buy the rattling cooling disc as well. I pressed small pieces of rubber between the disc and the spokes and it stopped the rattling without impairing the brake's function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check brake unit fixing nut torque. It's the shiny hex nut holding the roller brake to the hub.
2) Ensure sufficient lubrication of the roller brake moving parts.

I found the following page with photos and a youtube video very helpful in putting the brake together.

http://sandyfoto.ru/printsip_raboty_rollernogo_tormoza_i_yego_ustroystvo.html

I had a similar issue with my BR-IM81-F (front) roller brake. The rattle has gotten progressively worse until it was always rattling, unless I was applying the brake.

Upon disassembly of the roller brake I discovered that the fixing nut was barely finger tight and that there was very little grease on the moving parts. Upon remedying these two issues, the rattle is completely gone.